# Apache 2 block url such as example.com/?admin

Tags: php, apache

Please can you tell me in Apache2 how I can restrict a url to my IP address when the url is generated as a script. For example:

```
example.com/?admin
```

I have tried Location Match but no joy:

```
<LocationMatch /?admin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from [MY IP]
    Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: "but no joy" --- what does it mean?

Comment: it would be better to do this in php and not in your .htaccess file since ?admin is not a directory

Comment: Sorry no joy means it did not work. I see, so I would check for my url and then display an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to match the %{QUERY_STRING} and disallow anything that's not empty, unless it's from your IP.  Check the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite) for examples.